# Prevent user from submitting form if form is still the same

Tags: angular, angular7

So I want to prevent a user from submitting a form if the form is untouched/still the same. The form has a submit button which calls my `submitChanges()` function when clicked. This is what my function looks like in the TS.

```
submitChanges() {
// Do nothing if the form is still the same
if (!this.myForm.dirty || this.myForm.invalid) {
   return;
}

else
//...submit the form...
}
```

Problem: The logic seems to be working until I type something in the form and backspace whatever I typed. It thinks the form is still dirty even though I backspaced everything I typed, so the question is how can the form know it's not dirty anymore since the input has been removed (backspaced)?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method and on focusout of the input that does this:

```
if(this.form.controls.formControl.value === '') {
   this.formControl.markAsPristine();
   this.formControl.markAsUntouched();
}
```

It will prevent you from being able to submit the form. I'd also recommend using the `[disabled]` attribute to prevent the user from being able to click on the button if the form is not valid.

Comment: that's not prevent in a control with "original value", e.g. `123`, it's used backspace (value is `12`) and click 3, (value again `123`)

Comment: Please also note that the form has pre-existing/original values that can be changed. It's a form that pops up when the user wants to make changes/updates.

Answer (score 0):

the only you make a custom form validator

```
  isEqual(value:string)
  {
    return (control)=>{
      return control.value==value?{error:'must be different to '+value}:
                            null
    }
  }
```

You use like, e.g.

```
  control=new FormControl('one',this.isEqual('one'))
```

see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnhreh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)